# SDL2 + ffmpeg2 intermittent clicks instead of audio

Tags: c++, audio, ffmpeg, sdl

Using c++, SDL2, SDL2_mix, ffmpeg2.

Inited SDL2_mix with callback

```
Mix_HookMusic(MusicPlayer, &g_audioPos);
```

Decoded audio from ogg to AVFrame* by this code:

```
while(av_read_frame(m_formatContext, &m_packet) >= 0)
{
    if(m_packet.stream_index == m_audioStream)
    {
        int audio_frame_finished;
        avcodec_decode_audio4(m_audioCodecContext, m_audioFrame, &audio_frame_finished, &m_packet);
        if(!audio_frame_finished)
        {
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

After this code i have frame with some `m_audioFrame->data[0]` and `m_audioFrame->linesize[0] == 4096`

Once in a while my callback being called:

```
void MusicPlayer(void *_udata, Uint8 *_stream, int _len)
    {
        if(!g_audioData)
        {
            return;
        }

        AudioData* audio = reinterpret_cast<AudioData*>(g_audioData);

        if(!audio || audio->Frame->linesize[0] == 0)
        {
            return;
        }

        SDL_memcpy((Uint8*)audio->Data + audio->Pos, (Uint8*)audio->Frame->data[0], audio->Frame->linesize[0]);

        audio->Pos+= audio->Frame->linesize[0];
        int rest = g_chunkSize - audio->Pos;//frame->linesize[0];


        if(rest <= 0)
        {
            SDL_memcpy(_stream, audio->Data, _len);
            audio->Pos = 0;
            *(int*)_udata += _len;
        }
    }
```

_len == 8192, so i must push 2 frames to fill stream, but all i get - clicks in my speaker. What am i doing wrong?

PS: Tried to reopen MIX with `Mix_OpenAudio(m_audioCodecContext->sample_rate, AUDIO_S16SYS, m_audioCodecContext->channels, 4096);`. Interesting thing is `m_audioCodecContext->channels == 2` and when my callback being called `_len = 16384`. Have no idea what to do. Please help!!!

Comment: last release. almost an hour spent to figure out: dranger tutorial not work well with latest ffmpeg lib, because some of defs and methods are deprecated, also - prety big chunk of code now can be replaced with avcodec_decode_audio4 method... if i understood correctly. Point is - i did some search to find out how to make thing ALMOST work. It is first time i'm working with audio (

Answer (score 0):

You did not show how you perform the ffmpeg initialization; I'd speculate you forgot to specify the requested sample format:

```
aCodecCtx->request_sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16;
```

Take a look at the source code of my Karaoke lyrics editor which uses the SDL/ffmpeg audio player based on the latest ffmpeg (and hence decode_audio4): https://sourceforge.net/p/karlyriceditor/code/HEAD/tree/src/audioplayerprivate.cpp

Comment: thank you for code. rewrote callback, sound a bit better, but still not working. please take a look at this https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8615126

Comment: Well, I'd suggest to change your code to something which works (such as mine or any other SDL-based player), and then start implementing your own changes. The way your code is written you'd likely get sound buffer underflow, and therefore clicks.

Comment: Thanks. Just figure things out "aCodecCtx->request_sample_fmt" not works well, it will decode in "aCodecCtx->sample_fmt" anyway. At first i just reopened SDL_mixer with float sample format, but it didn't work at IOS, so finaly - i used "swr_convert" to convert my sound data. One thing left is - before i grab enough sound data - i decode prety big bunch of video frames, so my sound plying with delay.